# How to generate a random integer between certain values from an array of bytes

Tags: c#, random

I am developing a program in which I need to generate a random number from an array of bytes which is received from a device which generates random numbers. The problem is; the device sends the random numbers as a stream of bytes, and I need it to generate an integer between a certain value. In other words:

```
int GenerateRandom(int min, int max, byte[] rndr) {
//Do something with the bytes to make a random integer here between min and max
}
```

No, I can't use the built-in Random class in .NET, because the program will be used to encrypt secure information, and a pseudo-random-number generator would not be acceptable.

Comment: @Mitch: Can you post a link to the duplicate question?

Comment: Need a specific answer for C#

Comment: Would you explain what do you want with example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Random.java.html) for the `java.util.Random` class may help you. I know, I know, it's not C#, but don't downvote just yet. The algorithm is the important bit: given a source of random bits, generate an integer between 0 and n. It's pretty trivial to convert the range [0..n] to [min..max].

I'm sure you can implement the same algorithm in C# in a similar amount of code: around 12 lines, including 2 close braces and 2 lines of input validation.

EDIT: The `nextInt(int n)` function is the one you want to look at.

EDIT2: Alternatively, you could use a `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` seeded with your high-quality random bits. That may be secure enough for your purposes, especially if you can reseed every so often with new, high-quality randomness.

Interestingly, the msdn website does not work correctly with Chrome on Linux. Who'd have thunk?

Comment: if he really needs an algorithm, implementing this is C# should not prove too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a cryptograhically strong random number then the .NET framework has the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) class for this purpose.

[GetBytes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes.aspx) fills an array of bytes with a cryptographically strong sequence of random values.

Comment: RNGCryptoServiceProvider still won't be as good as the OP's source of randomness. From the question: "a pseudo-random-number generator would not be acceptable". RNGCryptoServiceProvider is still pseudo-random, but better than the vanilla Random class.

Answer (score 0):

If this array of bytes already contains a random number, you can use it as a sample value. In this example I am using the first 4 bytes, you can modify this for whatever word size is applicable and make it rotate words.

```
static int GenerateRandom(int min, int max, byte[] rndr)
{
    int isamp = (int)(((uint)rndr[3] << 24) | ((uint)rndr[2] << 16) | ((uint)rndr[1] << 8) | ((uint)rndr[0]));
    if (isamp < 0)
        isamp += int.MaxValue;
    double samp = isamp * 4.6566128752457969E-10;
    return (int)(samp * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't result in equally likely values from the output interval.

Comment: That would depend on the distribution of the input seeds. It's as equally distributed as the is the input.